# How to set the HTTP-Session-Timeout in Jetty 9 (embedded)?

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I would like to use Jetty 9 (v9.2.12.v20150709) embedded for my test cases.
But I am unable to change the HTTP-Session-Timeout programmatically.

This call `webapp.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeoutInSeconds);` doesn't seem to work.

Here is reduced code segement, which shows what I do:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.ContentResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class EmbeddedJetty
{

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class TimeoutServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
        {
            // return the value of the currently used HTTP-Session Timeout
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            response.getWriter().println("<h1>Timeout: " + request.getSession()
                    .getMaxInactiveInterval() + "</h1>");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // the custom timeout, which I am trying to set
        int timeoutInSeconds = 1234;

        Server server = new Server(0);
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setResourceBase(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        // Can't set custom timeout. Following Statement doesn't work.
        webapp.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager().setMaxInactiveInterval(
                timeoutInSeconds);

        server.setHandler(webapp);

        webapp.addServlet(TimeoutServlet.class.getName(), "/*");

        server.start();

        // get current URL of the server
        String url = server.getURI().toString();
        System.out.println("\n URL: " + url);
        // server.dumpStdErr();

        // make a request to get the used timeout setting
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.start();
        ContentResponse response = httpClient.GET(url);
        httpClient.stop();

        String timeoutInfo = response.getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(timeoutInfo);

        // check if the custom timeout is used
        if( timeoutInfo.contains(String.valueOf(timeoutInSeconds)) )
        {
            System.out.println("Custom Timeout is used.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Unfortunately, I get the default(?) everytime
            System.out.println("Default Timeout? Custom Value is NOT used.");
        }

        System.out.println("Press Enter to exit ...");
        System.in.read();

        server.stop();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

I am using the `WebAppContext`-Style of setup, because this allowed me to get my `ServletContextListener`s to work by using `WebAppContext.addEventListener()`. Which I couldn't get to work by using a `ServletHandler`.

Also I am using the Version 9.2.12.v20150709 of Jetty, because it is Classpath-compatible with `Selenium v2.5.2` (which supports Java 7 (project requirement)).

Have you any suggestions, what i am doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: [Jetty 9.2.x is EOL (End of Life)](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg08361.html) btw.

Comment: What Session manager are you using?  From your code example, you either have none, or a dummy no-op version.  (Only some session manager implementations support that configuration)

Comment: `ServletHandler` isn't meant to be used directly (its an internal class that has no concept of a ServletContext, which a ServletContextListener needs), you are meant to use `ServletContextHandler` or `WebAppContext`.

Comment: Yes, i haven't set a Session manager explicitly. According to the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/3b1533673ef0c22b876a60e4e827162b73371499/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/SessionHandler.java#L70), a `HashSessionManger` is used by default. Which in turn [implements](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/3b1533673ef0c22b876a60e4e827162b73371499/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/session/HashSessionManager.java#L249) the `setMaxInactiveInterval`-Method.

Comment: The `ServletHandler`-Variant is shown in an [embedded example of Jetty 9.3](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedded-examples.html#embedded-minimal-servlet). But as you guessed, i also tried `ServletContextHandler`, where I couldn't get the EventListeners to work.

Answer (score 5):

A WebAppContext has some defaults, which are loaded during `server.start()` (`WebAppContext.startContext()`).
These defaults contain also a DefaultWebDescriptor located in the jetty-webapp.jar under `/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml`. This Descriptor includes a `session-config`, which sets the timeout to the default of 30m (1800s).

To overwrite the defaults the call of `setMaxInactiveInterval()` must be done after the server is started:

```
server.start();
webapp.getSessionHandler().getSessionManager().setMaxInactiveInterval(timeoutInSeconds);
```

Or to avoid these defaults, it might be better to use a `ServletContextHandler` instead.

Comment: If using `WebAppContext`, you can provide [your own override descriptor](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.8.v20171121/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#setOverrideDescriptor-java.lang.String-) to provide an overlay of configuration on top of the default descriptor.

Comment: That link died - maybe https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html ?